# Bootstrap-Select skipping tab-index

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using [1.6.3](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-select) of this [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) for select menus with Bootstrap.

However, when I tab through my form, it skips over the `select` elements the have class `selectpicker`: i.e. the element isn't in the tab order.

There is a 1.6.4 version on GitHub, but I can' find it on a CDN.

Wondering if anyone else has run into that issue and if there is a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab order should naturally roughly follow the order of the HTML elements in the DOM.

Here's an example of it working just fine with version 1.6.3

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Something</label>
  <select class="selectpicker form-control">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="something">Something</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="something">
</div>
```

If you remove the bootstrap-select, and just let the regular `<select>` element be part of the form, does it still have issues?  If so, bootstrap select isn't the root of the problem.

Either way, we'll probably need a working demo to diagnose the problem.  You can take the Stack Snippet in this answer and start adding to it until you can recreate the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with Bootstrap v3.3.7 and Bootstrap-select v1.12.4 - The tab index doesn't work. When removing the *selectpicker* class, the tab index works. Any suggestions?

Comment: @manu - suggestions... create a thoughtful, well-composed, brief [mcve] if you want the internet to be able to debug what's happening on your machine.  It'll be hard to give more specific advice without seeing what's broken.

Comment: I tested your code with Safari Version 11.0.2 and it doesn't work. I tested it with Chrome and it worked (also my example). So I guess there's something dependent on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, had the same problem, specially on macbooks, there some preferences skipp the button elements generated by bootstrap select

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        fixTabulation();
    });


function fixTabulation() {
    /* This can be used to auto-assign tab-indexes, or
    #  commented out if it manual tab-indexes have
    #  already been assigned.
    */
    $('[tabindex]:not([tabindex="0"]):not([tabindex^="-"])').filter(":visible").each(function () {           
        $(this).attr('tabindex', Tab.i);
        Tab.i++;
        Tab.items++;
    });

    Tab.i = 0;

    /* We need to listen for any forward or backward Tab
    #  key event tell the page where to focus next.
    */
    $(document).on({
        'keydown': function (e) {                
            if (navigator.appVersion.match("Safari")) {                    
                if (e.keyCode == 9 && !e.shiftKey) { //Tab key pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Tab.i != Tab.items ? Tab.i++ : Tab.i = 1;                        
                    if ($('[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').prop('class').match('dropdown-toggle'))
                        $('[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').click();
                    else
                        $('input[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], select[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], textarea[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus();
                }
                if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) { //Tab key pressed
                    e.preventDefault();
                    Tab.i != 1 ? Tab.i-- : Tab.i = Tab.items;
                    if ($('[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').prop('class').match('dropdown-toggle'))
                        $('[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').click();
                    else
                        $('input[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], select[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"], textarea[tabindex="' + Tab.i + '"]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    /* We need to update Tab.i if someone clicks into
    #  a different part of the form.  This allows us
    #  to keep tabbing from the newly clicked input
    */
    $('button[tabindex], input[tabindex], select[tabindex], textarea[tabindex]').not('input[type="hidden"]').focus(function (e) {
        Tab.i = $(this).attr('tabindex');
        console.log(Tab.i);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a 'feature' of Safari that tabs skip dropdowns. Its part of the browser settings. Looks like it affects Firefox too.

http://www.tonyspencer.com/2006/05/02/tab-skips-select-form-fields-in-mac-browsers/index.html